# Can you change the character set that is used to encode the SQL queries sent to the MySQL server and the data received from the MySQL server?

Tags: mysql, character-encoding

Let's say that I want to send the following SQL query to the MySQL server:

```
SELECT * FROM students;
```

Which character set will be used to encode the above statement, and which character set will be used to encode the response from the MySQL server? and can you change this character set?

Comment: google search  "mysql character set"  -> 1st result: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset.html

Comment: @Georg Richter I saw that page before asking this question, but I am not 100% sure it is what I'm looking for, so you're saying I should use `SET NAMES 'utf8mb4';`?

Comment: Related: [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/)

Answer (score 1):

Look at system variables of your MySQL server and definition of database and tables:

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES like '%char%';

mysql> show create database <your_database_name>;

mysql> show create table <your table, like "students">;
```

By default tables have database charset.

MySQL automatically changes the encoding of strings when entering data into the table and when fetching data from the table. It uses data from system variables, such as character_set_client for this.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not quite right.  You need to specify the character set encoding in two places:  The bytes on the client and the bytes on the server.

**Client encoding**

Best:  Establish the in/out character set via connection parameters.  There you specify the encoding of the *client*.

Second best is `SET NAMES utf8mb4;` right after connecting (assuming you want `utf8mb4`).

**Server encoding**

The charset on each column (in the *database*) comes from the column definition.  If missing, then the default comes from the table definition.  Run `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

If client and server are not the same, MySQL will transcode when `INSERTing` and when `SELECTing`.

If you have specific symptoms, see [Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored)